# Should I use telerik radgrid or windsor container for developing .NET applications

Tags: c#, asp.net

I recently was given some code in c# ASP.NET and I was going through it and it seems as though the person who coded this before me used telerik radgrid and windsor container.  I looked these up and I understand what telerik radgrid does (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdataglance.html), but If i am just starting out is it really worth it to use these plugins? or is it much better to just do it by scratch.  Also I was wondering if someone could explain what exactly does windsor container do: http://www.castleproject.org/container/gettingstarted/index.html and if it is necessary? The website is just a basic content management system as of right now.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Castle Windsor is a Dependency Injection (DI) Container. To get started with DI, take a look at the landing page for the dependency-injection tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=dependency-injection&sort=info&pagesize=50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what windsor container does - watch this [video](http://tekpub.com/view/concepts/1). It's about different tool called Ninject, but the idea is the same. For more details - read [this](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) book.

Can't tell much about telerik radgrid though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Such components mostly enhance the default controls that ship with ASP.NET. First make up your mind to see what your requirements are and if you need the control or can do it with the standard controls.
2. It's likely used as a dependency injection container. This is not really a necessary feature to use but I see it coming more and more common in new applications. It separates the dependencies out of the code that uses the dependency. To read more about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection.

Answer (score 0):

The windsor container is an inversion of control container like structuremap, ninject, spring.net or unity.

In short: these containers build your objects for you. You don't have to use new WhateverClass() yourself and they decouple your code implementations.

You should read up on "Inversion of Control" which is a really important technique to write better testable and maintainable code. Inversion of control Containers are tools helping you to implement this pattern.